# show all symbols option is not working in VS code Mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

`Command+T` is supposed to show symbols in Visual studio code for Mac machine.

It used to work for me in windows using `ctrl+t`

It is not working for me and it returns the following error:

```
----------Generating Tags----------
ctags --options=/xxxxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.44104/resources/ctagOptions --languages=Python --exclude=**/site-packages/** -o /Users/enxxven/Documents/scikit-learn/.vscode/tags .
> ctags --options=/xxxxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.44104/resources/ctagOptions --languages=Python --exclude=**/site-packages/** -o ~/Documents/scikit-learn/.vscode/tags .
cwd: ~/Documents/scikit-learn
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ctags: illegal option -- -
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `ctags` using brew solved the problem for me

```
brew install ctags
```

Now I am able to get the symbols using `command + T`.

Edit:

With new version, I got the same problem

```
Version: 1.42.1 
Commit: c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054
Date: 2020-02-11T14:44:27.652Z
Electron: 6.1.6
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.6.0
```

Now, I went to settings (cmd ,) and searched for symbols. 
Then, check the following option, which is under python.

[image]